# Can I make intellisense suggest definitions from files that are not (yet) included?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I love VSCode, so I'm trying to migrate to it for C++ development.

As you can see from the pictures below. Netbeans will suggest the type `std::map`, even though I haven't used `#include <map>` in my source code.

This is really neat. Netbeans adds the `#include` statement automatically for me (if I need it).

[image: Netbeans suggests std::map]

VSCode, however, does not suggest `std::map`. It won't do so until I have actually (manually) added `#include <map>` in my source.

Can I enable the VSCode intellisense to suggest types that I have not yet added an `include` statement for?

[image: VSCode does not suggest a type that is not included]

Comment: VSC is  (my opinion) still in its infancy. Suggest this to the developers and you may well see it in a future release.

Comment: I agree with you. But I suspect this feature actually exists in VSCode. I mean, what's this `browse` setting really for?: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

Comment: Certainly does sound like if you add your compiler's library implementation folder (and other stuff of interest) to the `"Path"` list and set `"limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false` should do something along the lines of what you want. And it could be for a feature that shows up next year. I'll have to reinstall and poke at it to see what happens.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I can't get VSCode to suggest definitions from not-yet-included source files.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4776